# How to prove $E(|T_{(1)}-T_{(2)}|)=O(n^{-1})$.

Tags: statistics, expected-value, order-statistics

> Suppose $T_i\sim F$ i.i.d. for $i=1,\,\cdots,\,n$ where $F$ has continuous density function $f$ on $[0,\,1]$ such that $\inf_{t\in[0,1]}f(t)>0$.
>
> Prove that $E(|T_{(1)}-T_{(2)}|)=O(n^{-1})$.

Here is what I have tried.

[image]

Comment: What’s $T_{(1)}$ and $T_{(2)}$

Comment: There are the first and second smallest ordered statistics.

Comment: Ok, can you change your variables to be $T_1,T_2,…$? Having both T and X is confusing. Edit: Ahh, seems like you just fixed.

Comment: In the second equality the $t_1/(n - 1)$ outside the integral should just be $t_1$